# Fixing Numpy failing to import multiarray

Tags: python, numpy

Ok, so I am trying to use matplotlib:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import matplotlib.rcsetup as rc
print(rc.all_backends)

plt.plot([1,2,3], [4,5,6])


plt.show()
```

But I get a error on the first line, when I try to import matplotlib:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Vineet\Documents\Summer 2017\Python\MathPlot\MathPlot\Intro.py", line 1, in <module>
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 122, in <module>
    from matplotlib.cbook import is_string_like, mplDeprecation, dedent, get_label
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\cbook.py", line 32, in <module>
    import numpy as np
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 142, in <module>
    from . import add_newdocs
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\numpy\add_newdocs.py", line 13, in <module>
    from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .type_check import *
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\type_check.py", line 11, in <module>
    import numpy.core.numeric as _nx
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError:
Importing the multiarray numpy extension module failed.  Most
likely you are trying to import a failed build of numpy.
If you're working with a numpy git repo, try `git clean -xdf` (removes all
files not under version control).  Otherwise reinstall numpy.
```

Essentially the main problem is the in the numpy library, when it tries to import the multiarray module:

```
File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
        raise ImportError(msg)
    ImportError:
    Importing the multiarray numpy extension module failed.  Most
    likely you are trying to import a failed build of numpy.
    If you're working with a numpy git repo, try `git clean -xdf` (removes all
    files not under version control).  Otherwise reinstall numpy.
```

I checked the file itself and there is no sign of multiarray. How do I fix this? I tried reinstalling numpy (1.13.1), but that didn't work. I looked through the internet but couldn't find a solution that would work for me.

OS: Window 10 
Python: 3.6 
Numpy: 1.13.1

Comment: it worked for me on py2.7.10 ubuntu , numpy 1.8.2 !

Comment: i had some similar problem... Things that worked for me: installing a lower version (`pip install numpy = 1.11.1`). And after reinstalling it for like 5 times and every time changing small things it worked (with the newest version), but I can't tell you why^^

Comment: @JürgMerlinSpaak I tried, but it won't let me: "Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement 1.11.1 (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for 1.11.1"

Comment: @VineetPatel Sorry, you need two =, so `pip install numpy==1.11.1`

Comment: @JürgMerlinSpaak Thanks for your input! The problem ended up being solved by updating Python from 3.6.0 to 3.6.2. Apparently there was some bug in python or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve by updating python to 3.6.2, apparently there was a bug with python when it came to implementing libraries or something.